# Prove that the vertices A,B,C,and D must all lie in the same plane. Assume the incidence axioms are valid.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Question: If the diagonals AC and BD of a quadrilateral ABCD intersect at some point E, prove that the vertices A,B,C,and D must all lie in the same plane. Assume the incidence axioms are valid.

Attempt and possible solution:
I started working on this problem by looking at the definition of quadrilateral.

By definition quadrilateral " It is the set of all points on segments AB,BC,CD,and DA such that no three vertices A,B,C, and D are collinear and no two sides meet except at end points. "

Let segments AC and BC be diagonals of the quadrilateral ABCD, they intersect at E.

By the definition of quadrilateral let A, B, C lies in a same plane and they don't lie on a same line (non-collinear).

Suppose D does not lie on the same plane as A,B, and C.

But D must be adjacent to A and C.

Now consider the plane containing the line joining AD and CD.

Join the other diagonal BD.

Now BD is a line intersecting the plane containing A, B and C at B.

Also BD lies on the plane other than A,B, and C. So BD can not intersect the other diagonal at any point E other than B.

But B is not a point on the diagonal AC.

That is a contradiction to our hypothesis.

Therefore we can conclude A,B,C, and D must lie on the same plane.

Comment: That's a trivial consequence of the fact that two lines with a point in common lie on the same plane.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca So should I try another way to prove this? I was trying to prove my contradiction but also attempted by just using the definition of quadrilateral and the incidence axioms but I felt it was too simple.

Comment: Just use the axiom stating that if two points lie in a plane, then the line containing these points lies in the same plane.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Thank you for your help. I will rework problem.

Answer (score 1):

Line $AE$ lies on plane $ABE$. Line $BE$ lies on plane $ABE$. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the diagonals as vectors , now as these vectors are intersecting , they are coplanar .